# ASP.Net: Setting the correct currency settings for string.Format()

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting, currency, culture

In my ASP.Net Website I am using

```
String.Format("{0:C}", param)
```

to format currency values. On my local machine this works great, but when deploying the website to the server the output switches from € to $.

Obviously the server has different Culture settings, is there an easy way to change this application wide? (without direct access to the servers settings)

Is there an web.config entry I can change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in web.config

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

In an ASP.NET Web page, you can set to two culture values, the Culture and UICulture properties. The Culture value determines the results of culture-dependent functions, such as the date, number, and currency formatting, and so on. The UICulture value determines which resources are loaded for the page.

Example

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var culture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
        culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 3;
        Trace.WriteLine(Cost.ToString("c", culture));
```